# Improper Header Placement in Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, header

I have a large header image that I'd like to use for both tablet devices and phones.  The image looks fine on a tablet but when viewed on a phone it looks like this:
[image]

Here is my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@color/white"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/searchresults_header" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

How can I get this header image to scale correctly on both screen sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is getting resized automatically, but the viewbounds stay as they were originally.

Add this to your `ImageView` and you should see the difference:

`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember which one but try these [scaleType param values](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType)